# WiX installer fails with Error 0x80070570: Failed to extract all files from container, erf: 1:4:0

Tags: windows-7, windows-installer, wix

I have created an MSI installer bootstrapper (so `.exe`) with WiX, it works on my computer (Windows 7) but when executed on another Windows 7 computer it fails with:

```
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:25]i001: Burn v3.8.1128.0, Windows v6.3 (Build 9600: Service Pack 0), path: C:\TheCorp\MyApp.exe, cmdline: '-burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{8CBF07E2-8344-4B12-B6EF-849AFF20A241} {15F194D4-BB1E-45C9-AFC6-DE29F3F5FBD4} 3364'
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallFolder' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]MyApp'
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:25]i000: Initializing string variable 'LaunchTarget' to value '[InstallFolder]\MyApp.exe'
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:31]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\THECOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MyApp_20160111022131.log'
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:31]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\TheCorp\MyApp.exe'
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:31]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'MyApp'
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:32]i100: Detect begin, 2 packages
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:32]i000: Setting string variable 'NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT' to value '1'
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:32]i052: Condition 'NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT' evaluates to true.
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:32]i101: Detected package: NetFx40ClientWeb, state: Present, cached: None
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:32]i101: Detected package: MyApp.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:32]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[1688:07C0][2016-01-11T02:21:37]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[1688:07C0][2016-01-11T02:21:43]i000: Setting numeric variable 'EulaAcceptCheckbox' to value 1
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:43]i200: Plan begin, 2 packages, action: Install
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:43]w321: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: NetFx40ClientWeb
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:43]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_MyApp.msi' to value 'C:\Users\THECOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MyApp_20160111022131_0_MyApp.msi_rollback.log'
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:43]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_MyApp.msi' to value 'C:\Users\THECOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\MyApp_20160111022131_0_MyApp.msi.log'
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:43]i201: Planned package: NetFx40ClientWeb, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:43]i201: Planned package: MyApp.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: Register
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:43]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:21:43]i300: Apply begin
[0D24:0D6C][2016-01-11T02:22:53]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0D24:0D6C][2016-01-11T02:23:08]i361: Created a system restore point.
[0D24:0D6C][2016-01-11T02:23:11]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\THECOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{bc2e9f37-0003-4eca-9db4-f291fb8e74cf}\.be\MyApp.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{bc2e9f37-0003-4eca-9db4-f291fb8e74cf}\MyApp.exe'
[0D24:0D6C][2016-01-11T02:23:11]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {bc2e9f37-0003-4eca-9db4-f291fb8e74cf}, version: 2.6.5.0
[1688:1038][2016-01-11T02:23:11]i336: Acquiring container: WixAttachedContainer, copy from: C:\TheCorp\MyApp.exe
[1688:1038][2016-01-11T02:23:11]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLastUsedSource' to value 'C:\TheCorp\'
[1688:0A00][2016-01-11T02:23:12]e000: Error 0x80070570: Failed to extract all files from container, erf: 1:4:0
[1688:1038][2016-01-11T02:23:12]e000: Error 0x80070570: Failed to begin and wait for operation.
[1688:1038][2016-01-11T02:23:12]e000: Error 0x80070570: Failed to extract payload: a0 from container: WixAttachedContainer
[1688:1038][2016-01-11T02:23:12]e312: Failed to extract payloads from container: WixAttachedContainer to working path: C:\Users\THECOR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{bc2e9f37-0003-4eca-9db4-f291fb8e74cf}\DABA1C8CC6C8ECC2B828E87BD7C6969994023CCC, error: 0x80070570.
[1688:1078][2016-01-11T02:23:12]e000: Error 0x80070570: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
```

The most interesting part is probably `Failed to extract all files from container`.
What does it mean?
Any idea what could be causing the error on that particular computer?

Comment: 0x80070570 = ERROR_FILE_CORRUPT. so your Installer is corrupted or the Filesystem C:\ has issue. if you file is fine, check the filesystem with chkdsk C: /f